# facebook share doesn't display the 'correct' image (Provided og:image URL, was not a valid URL)

Tags: facebook, image, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sharer

I have facebook share button on my site. when i try to share my post it displays 'other' image (not that one, which displayed on post). i have meta tag for image(here's image that it should display while sharing)

```
<meta content="http://radioclassic.gbtimes.ge:80/uploads/all/SISALTO/4663124092_3b6eed4178_o.jpg"
```

the image path is correct(i entered it in address bar and it works). facebook debugger says that `Provided og:image URL, was not a valid URL.`, but url is valid
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

didn't know that after make changes i should hit `scrape again` button. now it works